# I try to add data from data grid view to sql database but getting error 'The parameterized query which was not supplied.' vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to add data from data grid view to sql database,the data saved to database but keep getting this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@KodeBuku nvarchar(4000),@JudulBuku nvarchar(4000),@PenerbitBuk' expects the parameter '@KodeBuku', which was not supplied.'

My code

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_buku.Rows
        Dim constring As String = "data source=MSI;initial catalog=DB_PERPUS;integrated security=true"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(constring)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into Tbl_Buku values(@KodeBuku,@JudulBuku,@PengarangBuku,@PenerbitBuku,@TahunBuku,@StokBuku)", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KodeBuku", row.Cells("kode").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JudulBuku", row.Cells("judul").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PenerbitBuku", row.Cells("penerbit").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PengarangBuku", row.Cells("pengarang").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StokBuku", row.Cells("stok").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TahunBuku", row.Cells("tahun").Value)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
    MsgBox("Save")
```

Answer (score 2):

That indicates that the `Value` of the cell in that column for at least one row was `Nothing`, which won't work with ADO.NET. If you want to insert NULL then you have to use `DBNull.Value`. The way you're doing things, that means explicitly checking for `Nothing`. You also should not be using `AddWithValue`, but rather calling `Add` and specifying the data type and, optionally, the size, e.g.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@KodeBuku", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
    If(row.Cells("kode").Value, DBNull.Value)
```

I'm not 100% sure without testing but you may have to use `CObj(DBNull.Value)`. Note that that `If` operator will return the first argument if it's not `Nothing` and the second if it is.

A better option would be to not use a loop to call `ExecuteNonQuery` in the first place. You should create a `DataTable` with the appropriate schema and bind that to the grid. You can then use a data adapter with an appropriate `InsertCommand` to save all the data with a single call to `Update`. Every field in a `DataTable` contains `DBNull.Value` by default, so there's no need to do any check for `Nothing`.

If you do want to go the `DataTable` option, you can do like this:

```vb
Private ReadOnly connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Private ReadOnly adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1", connection)
Private ReadOnly table As New DataTable
```

and this:

```vb
Dim command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@Column1, @Column2)", connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Column1")
    .Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Column2")
End With

adapter.InsertCommand = command
adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source)

BindingSource1.DataSource = table
DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

and this:

```vb
BindingSource1.EndEdit()
adapter.Update(table)
```

You can add the columns to the table manually if you want, instead of calling `FillSchema`.

Comment: thankyou, any example code or source for create datatable?